# Flux model parameters collapse to zero

Tags: machine-learning, julia

I have been working with the Flux.jl library, and desire to create a simple Proof-of-Concept autoencoder. Having referenced the [model zoo](http://https:/github.com/FluxML/model-zoo/blob/master/vision/mnist/autoencoder.jl), I created the following toy model, which takes input along the y=x^2 curve
in R^2 and attempts to reconstruct after sending it to a 1-D code layer representation:

```
using Flux
using Flux: @epochs, onehotbatch, mse, throttle#, params
using Base.Iterators: partition
using Distributions
##creating simple 2-1-2 AE
function build_train_data()
    function gen()
        x=rand(Uniform(0,1),1,10)
        y=x.^2
        xy = vcat(x,y)
        return xy
    end
    
    train_data=[gen() for i in 1:10]
    return train_data
end

function train()
    train_data=build_train_data()
    encoder=Dense(2,1,relu)
    decoder=Dense(1,2,relu)
    model = Chain(
        encoder,
        decoder
    )

    @info("Training model.....")
    loss(x) = mse(model(x),x)
    lr=1e-3
    opt = ADAM(lr)
    evalcb = throttle(() -> @show(loss(train_data[1])), 1)
    @epochs 100 Flux.train!(loss, Flux.params(model), zip(train_data), opt, cb = evalcb)
    return model
end

m =train()
td=build_train_data()
```

Now, I'm not expecting the moon from this model. That being said, I did not anticipate yielding the following results:

```
x=[0.9860286863631649 0.9209976855681348 0.6793548732252492 0.909752849042454 0.6926766153752839 0.9622926489586887 0.9639670701324241 0.8053711974593387 0.19502650255217913 0.38968830975794666; 0.9722525703310686 0.8482367368218608 0.46152304377489445 0.8276502463408622 0.479800893487759 0.9260071422399301 0.9292325122996898 0.6486227656970891 0.03803533669773513 0.15185697876200538]
m(x)=Float32[0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0; 0.96854496 0.84631497 0.46364155 0.8260073 0.4818032 0.92298573 0.9261639 0.6491447 0.0359351 0.15342757]
Flux.params(m)=Params([Float32[0.058760125 1.4413338], Float32[-0.0049902047], Float32[-1.0241822; 0.6694982], Float32[0.0, -0.005099244]])
```

for one training round and

```
x=[0.4789886773906975 0.8739656341280784 0.8535570077535617 0.6553854355816602 0.5611963054162175 0.22277653137378484 0.8716704866290759 0.30803815544599367 0.6973631796646094 0.07522895316317268; 0.22943015306848968 0.7638159296368942 0.7285595654852137 0.4295300691725624 0.31494129321281245 0.04962938293093494 0.7598094372601699 0.09488750521057016 0.48631540435193427 0.00565939539402683]
m(x)=Float32[0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0]
Flux.params(m)=Params([Float32[-0.071433514 -0.4906463], Float32[0.0], Float32[-0.14397836; 0.5831637], Float32[0.0, 0.0]])
```

for another.

As you can see, in the former case, reconstruction seems to work well enough for the "x^2" row of inputs, which leads me to believe that the model is at least partially working. The source of this problem has eluded my usual suite of debugging techniques, which leads me to believe that the source of the problem could lie with typing, (lack of) GPU utilization, or something more idiosyncratically julian.

Comment: curiously, changing the activation function from "relu" to "leakyrelu" seems to obviate the problem.

Comment: I find your notation very confusing. What's `x` and `m(x)`. also I don't see how the "output" are "outputs". also they are on the same line making it very hard to read.

Comment: @xiaodai x is an input and m(x) is the model output for input x. I believe this is standard, although I could be wrong. I'm not sure what you mean by the output being outputs, but I believe that m(x) is a reconstruction of x. Also, could you elaborate on what you mean by "they" being on the same line? Thanks

Comment: Except in the code it's called `model` not `m`.

Comment: Anyway, after reading your post, I still don't understand what the issue is.

Comment: That is incorrect. "model" is defined in the train() function. In the global scope, I define m=train(). You are welcome to run the code on a local machine to verify. When you say that you don't understand what the issue is, do you mean that the source/cause of the issue is unclear, or that the nature of the issue is unclear?

Comment: "I did not anticipate yielding the following results:" why not?

Comment: "As you can see, the former output seems to work well enough for the "x^2" row of inputs," I don't see. How does anyone see? What does that sentence even mean?

Comment: "I expected X, but this is showing Y, and Y is bad because Z. Why aren't I seeing X because W." That would be a logic progression, but it's so confusing what is even issue you are pointing out that no one can reasonably be expected to answer anything.

Comment: could've just listed `train(x)` instead you used `m` by `setting m =train` which leads to confusion. the code was so long that's it cropped. Feels like trying to make it as hard as possible to read.

Comment: Ah, I see. This autoencoder takes inputs on the y=x^2 curve in R^2, reduces them to a 1-dimensional code, and then attempts to reconstruct them. When I define the training data build_train_data(), I do so as a list of batches of shape [2, batchsize], where the first row represents x and the second represents y=x^2. What was unexpected is that the AE reconstructed the second row of the input batch very well, but the first row poorly — or not at all, really, which leads me to suspect that something strange is possibly at play. Does this clarify? I can make some edits to improve the post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220656/discussion-between-josh-purtell-and-xiaodai).